# MySQL update column based on part of query result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get update one table column based on a MySQL query. 
Problem is the query results in two columns but I only need the category column to be updated.

***not_categorized***

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | category_lookup      | category1          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Chino                | *to be found*      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Rainjacket           | *to be found*      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

***title_match***

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | title                | category1          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Chino                | Trousers / Jeans   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Rainjacket           | Jackets / Coats    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**Query**

```
SELECT distinct not_categorized.id,  category_lookup
FROM not_categorized
left JOIN title_match ON  not_categorized.category_lookup LIKE CONCAT('%', title_match.title, '%')
group by id;
```

This gives me the right result. Based on the word "Chino" the category should be "Jeans/Trousers".

**Query Result**

```
-------------------------
| id | category         | 
-------------------------
| 1  | Trousers / Jeans |
-------------------------
| 2  | Jackets / Coats  |
-------------------------
```

How can I now update column "category1" in the "not_characterized" table?

This is not working:

```
update not_categorized
set category1 = **QUERY**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your data  you could use an inner join based on  title and category_lookup

```
  update not_categorized
  inner join title_match on not_categorized.category_lookup =  title_match.title
  set not_categorized.category1 = title_match.category1
```

Comment: Perfect, the only change i did was instead of = title_match.title I used LIKE CONCAT('%', title_match.title, '%'). Thank you for your help!